# Show user's public facebook feed in iphone tableview

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am new to iPhone. I am developing an iPhone app that will show London2012(Official London Olympic facebook page) facebook public feeds into tableView. I was using https://graph.facebook.com/259479457407/feed?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAF8ePSI8e9Sjpx8W19FMZC64oB0hD0ARj1cN6fIYsGZBYq6WdKNMza0e5URvwDQqZBiORm6CzPgRmaueyP7gaCvS6l65sVxg9eZAdFIZC  link to get JSON however it expires after every 2 hours . So I need a new access token.

Facebook page of london2012 is:[-https://www.facebook.com/London2012](https://www.facebook.com/London2012)

***Is there any way to show facebook user's public feed into iPhone tableview.***

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and after few hours access token expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388605/1105863

I am reposting the answer

Get your page json feed through this link:

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=259479457407&format=json

Parse and Enjoy...

Happy coding.